# Toggle on/off a display adapter

Tags: automation, device-manager

I am just looking for a simple icon on my desktop that enables/disables my dedicated GPU. I have a gaming laptop that I use for work too and I need a simple and easy way to disable the dGPU when I work and re-enable it when I play games without opening the whole device manager.

Basically looking for an automation tool.

Comment: Who made it? NVIDIA?

Comment: Yes, I know there is optimus running and it AI takes care of the work load shift between the Integrated and dedicated GPUs but I want a manual control